# How to re-use a C++ closure concurrently with variable arguments -- similar to JavaScript?

Tags: c++, closures

JavaScript creates a closure with the scope where it was created. For example:

```
function startGreeter( name, iterations, delay ) {
    function greeter() {
        console.log("greetings, "+name+"! i="+iterations);
        if( --iterations )
            setTimeout( greeter, delay );
    }
    setTimeout( greeter, delay );
}

startGreeter("Alex",3,1000);
startGreeter("Beth",2,1500);
```

JavaScript creates two distinct closure instances for the greeter() function; one for Alex and one for Beth. Of course, we could create dozens or hundreds of such instances; from an array of data, for example.

I would like to accomplish the same in C++; specifically, to be able to create N distinct simultaneous closure instances of a function.

```
void startGreeterTask( AsyncManager& asyncManager, std::string name, int iterations, longtime msDelay )
{
    TaskFunction greetingTask = [&]()
    {
        std::cout << "greetings, task " << name << "! iterations = " << iterations << std::endl;
        if( --iterations )
        {
            asyncManager.setTimeout( greetingTask, msDelay );
        }
    };
    asyncManager.setTimeout( greetingTask, msDelay );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    AsyncManager asyncManager;
    startGreeterTask( asyncManager, "Alex", 3, 1000 );
    startGreeterTask( asyncManager, "Beth", 2, 1500 );
    asyncManager.execute();
}
```

The AsyncManager provides the setTimeout() functionality and it works if I create multiple closures in the scope of main(). But in startGreetingTask(), the closure function greetingTask() does not work the same as the greeter() function in JavaScript. As I understand it, greetingTask() and all the referenced parameters fall out of scope when startGreeterTask() finishes executing, so the stack memory is freed. Calling startGreeterTask() a second time creates a confliting usage of stack memory, and a seg fault ensures.

How can startGreeterTask() be made to work like the startGreeter() function?

Comment: You have your closure capture local variables (e.g. `name`) by reference. Those variables are destroyed when the function returns, and the reference inside the lambda becomes dangling. Capture by value instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, that did help, up to a point. I changed the capture to value and added the keyword mutable, because the iterations variable needs to be updated in the closure. But greetingTask() calls setTimeout(greetingTask) and when the timer fires, std::function generates a std::bad_function_call exception and core dumps. So the greetingTask seems to be garbage-collected after the first execution.

Comment: Does `asyncManager.setTimeout` take the lambda by reference, by any chance, and store a reference or pointer to it? Then it has the same problem - it stores a reference to a local variable, which becomes dangling soon. It should take it by value (and store a copy), or you need to allocate the callback on the heap. There is no garbage collection in C++ - you need to think through the lifetimes of the objects you use.

Comment: `asyncManager.setTimeout` uses the assignment operator to store the std::function object. I cannot find source, so I can only guess if it is using a copy constructor or copy by reference. The puzzling part is that the asyncManager executes the closure function correctly the first time. But the trouble occurs after the closure function calls setTimeout on itself. The closure is being destroyed (not gc'ed, that was lazy of me) after the first execution. I admit I do not understand the lifetime rule here. I can only guess C++ destroys the function after it is called.

Comment: `TaskFunction` is a typedef for `std::function`, right? What happens is that the lambda attempts to copy `greetingTask` before `greetingTask` has been constructed - you basically have `int x = x;` situation, which exhibits undefined behavior. I don't see an easy way out, short of replacing the lambda with a proper named class. Recursive lambdas can be made to work while executed in the same context where they were created, but I don't think they would work with delayed execution. The fundamental problem is that there's no way for the closure object to refer to itself - no `this` pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Igor Tandetnik for pointing me in the right direction. I'm posting a complete answer here for others to find.

The solution was (a) use copy capture by default, (b) use reference capture for the class instance that I do not want copied, (c) add the `mutable` keyword to allow the captured variables to be modified, and (d) avoid the closure function reference to itself. Now, instead of calling itself, the closure calls the function in which the closure is defined. This form of self-reference, through a layer of indirection, loses a little bit of the flexibility and expression of the JavaScript idiom, but it is fully functional and solves the problem quite nicely.

That said, if someone else solves this particular closure self-reference problem, I would like to see the solution.

```
void greetTask( AsyncManager& asyncManager, std::string name, int iterations, longtime msDelay )
{
    TaskFunction greetingClosure = [=,&asyncManager]() mutable
    {
        std::cout << "greetings, task " << name << "! iterations = " << iterations << std::endl;
        if( --iterations )
        {
            greetTask( asyncManager, name, iterations, msDelay );
        }
    };

    asyncManager.setTimeout( greetingClosure, msDelay );
}
```